# Display three textures equally on openGL control - OpenTK C#

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, opentk

I have three textures which should display on an opengl control in a way that those three should equally be in it. Means texture1 should be in 0 to 0.33 of glcontrol. And texture2 should be in 0.33 to 0.66 And texture3 in remain place. I have done like below. But right portion of middle image get a blurred area. Please help to correct

```
   private void CreateShaders()
    {
        /***********Vert Shader********************/
        vertShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(vertShader, @"attribute vec3 a_position;
                                    varying vec2 vTexCoordIn; 
         void main() {
            vTexCoordIn=( a_position.xy+1)/2 ;                                 
            gl_Position = vec4(a_position,1);
          }");
           GL.CompileShader(vertShader);

        /***********Frag Shader ****************/
        fragShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(fragShader, @"
    uniform sampler2D sTexture1;
    uniform sampler2D sTexture2;
    uniform sampler2D sTexture3;     
    varying vec2 vTexCoordIn;
    void main ()
    {                                               
    vec2 vTexCoord=vec2(vTexCoordIn.x,vTexCoordIn.y);
    if ( vTexCoord.x<0.3 )
    gl_FragColor = texture2D (sTexture1, vec2(vTexCoord.x*2.0, vTexCoord.y));
    else if ( vTexCoord.x>=0.3 && vTexCoord.x<=0.6 )
    gl_FragColor = texture2D (sTexture2, vec2(vTexCoord.x*2.0, vTexCoord.y));
    else
    gl_FragColor = texture2D (sTexture3, vec2(vTexCoord.x*2.0, vTexCoord.y));
 }");
        GL.CompileShader(fragShader);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Means texture1 should be in 0 to 0.33 of glcontrol. And texture2 should be in 0.33 to 0.66 And texture3 in remain place.

If the texture coordinates are in range [0, 0.33] then `sTexture1` has to be drawn and the texture coordinates have to be mapped from [0, 0.33] to [0, 1]:

```c
if ( vTexCoord.x < 1.0/3.0 )
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture1, vec2(vTexCoord.x * 3.0, vTexCoord.y));
```

If the texture coordinates are in range [0.33, 0.66] then `sTexture2` has to be drawn and the texture coordinates have to be mapped from [0.33, 0.66] to [0, 1]:

```
else if ( vTexCoord.x >= 1.0/3.0 && vTexCoord.x < 2.0/3.0 )
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture2, vec2(vTexCoord.x * 3.0 - 1.0, vTexCoord.y));
```

f the texture coordinates are in range [0.66, 1] then `sTexture3` has to be drawn and the texture coordinates have to be mapped from [0.66, 1] to [0, 1]:

```
else if ( vTexCoord.x >= 2.0/3.0 )
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture2, vec2(vTexCoord.x * 3.0 - 2.0, vTexCoord.y));
```

Comment: it gets !. Can you please explain why need to multiply by 3 ? And also on last loop why minus with 2.0?

Comment: @nds map from [0.66, 1] to [0, 1] : `0.66*3 - 2 = 0` and `1*3 - 2 = 1`. Note, the texture coordinates fro each texture are in the range [0, 1]

Comment: thank you. looks like aspect ratio of texture is missing. for ex :if using below code : if ( vTexCoord.x <0.5 )
 gl_FragColor = texture2D (sTexture, vec2(vTexCoord.x*2.0, vTexCoord.y)); aspect ratio is correct. means when multiplying by 2

Comment: it is set as  gl_Position = vec4(a_position,1);

Comment: aspect means aspect ratio of image? or a keyword?

Comment: i have set  private void CameraOpenGL_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            glControl1.Width = this.Width;
            glControl1.Height = this.Height / 2;
        } 
GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height / 2));

because i need to see the opengl window  in full width of screen and in half of height. is that causing the issue?

Comment: aspectratio of window is  1.92598689. when trying with gl_Position =vec4(a_position.x /1.92598689, a_position.y, a_position.z,1); gets blank and blurred area

Comment: @nsds I can guess only. There is not enough information provided in your question.  Add a new question with the current shader cod and possibly add a screenshot of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D (sTexture3, vec2(vTexCoord.x*2.0, vTexCoord.y));
                                                     ^^^^
```

Multiplying x-coordinate by 2.0 leads to values exceeding 1.0 if x >= 0.5.  If your sampler is set up to CLAMP_TO_EDGE (which seems to be the case), this results in repeatedly sampling the same texel on the edge of the texture (which will appear as smearing / blurring as you mentioned).

Comment: I have these lines : GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
              GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge); when I'm commenting this lines a zoomed output is getting